# How to compress photos already uploaded to Google Plus / Google Photos ?

Tags: google-plus, google-photos

I reached my Google account storage limit because I didn't take care to the fact that the sync of my photos via Google Plus and Google Photos is done with the initial size of the photos (limited storage), not with a reduced size (unlimited storage). Now, I have to subscribe to a 3-10$/month fee in order to increase my storage to a bigger storage.

How can I ask Google Plus/Google Photos to reduce the size of all the photos already stored in the cloud (to the limit mentioned by Google) in order to avoid to have these photos counted in my storage quota ? Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2):

You can do so by visiting the [settings](https://photos.google.com/settings) and pressing `Recover storage`

[image: Recover Storage Button Circled in Blue]